# Question about Pandas resample of time, and ploting

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, resampling

I am new to Python and Pandas. I am trying to generate a bar graph that shows the difference between the last sample of each day. If my approach is wrong please let me know.

Sample starting data set

```
               DateTime         Data1       Data2
0   2019-11-10 21:05:12  1.000000e-08      0.000000
1   2019-11-10 21:05:26  1.000000e-08      0.000000
2   2019-11-10 21:13:28  1.000000e-08      0.000000
3   2019-11-10 21:20:17  1.000000e-08      0.000000
4   2019-11-10 21:29:50  1.000000e-08      0.000000
..                  ...           ...           ...
191 2019-11-13 10:05:31  4.918000e-05      0.000004
192 2019-11-13 10:15:32  4.918000e-05      0.000004
193 2019-11-13 10:25:33  4.918000e-05      0.000004
194 2019-11-13 10:35:34  4.918000e-05      0.000004
195 2019-11-13 10:45:35  4.918000e-05      0.000004
```

This give me the last entry for each day but it has an extra column with the same name “DateTime” on a new row. When I plot this the x axes is using the “DateTime” with the time still in it. I wan to use the column that only has the date.

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
res = df.resample('D', on='DateTime').last()
res.plot(kind='bar', x='DateTime')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
print(res)
```

results of print

```
                      DateTime         Data1         Data2
DateTime                                                  
2019-11-10 2019-11-10 22:00:14  1.000000e-08  0.000000e+00
2019-11-11 2019-11-11 22:31:05  8.460000e-06  1.100000e-07
2019-11-12 2019-11-12 23:13:15  3.718000e-05  3.240000e-06
2019-11-13 2019-11-13 10:25:33  4.918000e-05  4.010000e-06
```

This give me the delta when compared with previous day. But it still had the two columns with the same name. When I try to plot it it uses the “DateTime” column that has “ 1 days 00:30:51”, and I need the other column.

```
res2 = pd.DataFrame()
res2 = res.diff()
res2.drop(res2.index[0], inplace=True)
res2.plot(kind='bar', x='DateTime')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
print(res2)
```

results of print

```
                  DateTime     Data1         Data2
DateTime                                          
2019-11-11 1 days 00:30:51  0.000008  1.100000e-07
2019-11-12 1 days 00:42:10  0.000029  3.130000e-06
2019-11-13 0 days 11:12:18  0.000012  7.700000e-07
```

Can any one explain what is happening, and how I can get the bar graph that I need?

Comment: ALollz thank you for helping me with the formatting of my question. This is my first post.

Comment: `res = df.set_index('Datetime').resample('D').last()`?

Comment: Quang, Thank you that worked. A follow up question, the bar graph shows the date and time example "2019-11-12 00:00:00". Is there a way to just show the day and month?

Comment: You can look up `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

Quang, thank you for your help. The following is the code I am using.

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
res = df.set_index('DateTime').resample('D').last()
res.plot(kind='bar')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
print(res)

res2 = pd.DataFrame()
res2 = res.diff()
res2.drop(res2.index[0], inplace=True)
ax = res2.plot(kind='bar', rot=20)
f = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b %d')
ax.set_xticklabels([ f(x.get_text()) for x in ax.get_xticklabels()])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
print(res2)
```